# I need help with using Like with weather

Tags: grammar

what do you think the weather will be like next week?
Or
what do you think the weather likes next week?

What is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: The second sentence doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the two words that are spelled "like".  These words are very different in meaning. That the spelling is the same is mostly co-incidence.

If you say "John likes cheese"  You mean that he enjoys eating it.  He loves cheese.  "Likes" is a verb.

If you say "John is like cheese" you mean that he is similar to cheese. He might be smelly! "Like" is an adjective.

So if you ask "What will the weather be like?"  You ask about what the weather will be similar to.  If you ask "What do you think the weather likes" You are asking what the weather loves.

But the weather can't love, because the weather isn't a person. The sentence "What do you think the weather likes?"  doesn't make any sense! It is correct grammar, it is just nonsense.

You have to say "What do you think the weather will be like?"

<sub>The words are related, perhaps from a sense of "I like cheese = cheese is similar to my preferences" The words were different in Old and Middle English, and it is only a modern simplification that they came to have the same spelling.</sub>